# How to use extern in C correctly

Tags: c

Let's say I have two C modules: The first module is a "file1.c" and "file1.h". The second module is "file2.c" and "file2.h". The first source file contains a variable called `sharedVariable`.

file1.c

```
/* Includes */
#include "stdlib.h"

int sharedVariable; // Global variable

/* Some C code */
```

file2.c

```
/* Includes */
#include "stdlib.h"

extern int sharedVariable; // Global variable

/* Some C code */
```

My question is: To make `sharedVariable` visible in file2.c, should I add `#include "file1.h"`? If yes, should I put something in it or I just leave it empty? If adding the header of the first file is unnecessary, how could the compiler identify the origin of `sharedVariable`?

**EDIT:**

I am looking for good practices to share a variable between two files. One of them is the owner and the other one is just a kind of reader. I used to put getters and setters in the owner file (setters are static functions) and expose the getter to the other one. But I am just curious about extern in C. Is it a good practice to use it instead?

Comment: How do you compile and link the `.c` files? Also what are the contents of the header files?

Comment: Unless you need something else from `file1.h`, then you don't need to include it. However, it might be a good idea to move the declaration from `file2.c` into `file1.h` and include it. Then you will have the declaration in a single place and can reuse it in multiple source file.

Comment: A better idea might be to not use global variables at all, if possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am looking for good practices to share a variable between two files. One of them is the owner and the other one is just a kind of reader. I used to put getters and setters in the owner file (setters are static functions) and expose the getter to the other one. But I am just curious about extern in C. Is it a good practice to use it instead?

Comment: You should move the `extern int sharedVariable;` line into `file1.h`.  Both `file1.c` and `file2.c` will include `file1.h`, so that the header can be used to cross-check that the files have a consistent view of the variable.  You should not declare `extern` variables in a source file; you should include the correct header.  You should not define variables in header files (so adding `int sharedVariable;` to `file1.h` would be a disaster.  Headers declare the facilities made available by a source file.  They're the glue that holds a project together.